# JQuery flicker when animating opacity, and opacity reaches 1

Tags: jquery

Here's a fiddle of the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/MaXaS/2/

Here's the markup (copied + pasted from jsfiddle, so script tags etc. missing):

```
tr
{
    visibility:hidden;
    background-color:#cccccc;
}

<table>
    <thead>            
        <th style='width:100px'>Bibble</th>
        <th style='width:100px'>Fish</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Some data!</td>
        <td>Some more data!</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$(document).ready(function()
                  {
      $('tr').css('visibility', 'visible').css('opacity', 0).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 2000);                    
                  });
```

If I animate to 0.9999 opacity, it's fine. What's happening when opacity reaches 1, and how can I help it?

Comment: What browser are you viewing this in? It seems to work fine in Google Chrome

Comment: I'm using Firefox - I agree, it works fine in Chrome!

Comment: why don't you try by giving CSS to table instead of tr.. 
this will reduce load also as it applies css to whole table instead of all rows...
demo : http://jsfiddle.net/MaXaS/12/

Comment: Its working fine for me, in firefox too

Comment: I am fading in rows one by one =)

Comment: hey flickering is your problem or tr width is your problem ?

Comment: flickering is the problem, `display:block` stops the flickering but breaks the table.

Comment: you want to apply css to `tr` only ?

Comment: I've pretty much given up on this and just switched to creating my table from many <divs>, which works fine. Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 4):

It's a known bug on Firefox : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656948

There is an hack to avoid this comportment : http://jsfiddle.net/7v7Rg/
You must do the animation to 0.999 opacity, wait a moment (one second is working for me) and set opacity at 1.

Comment: This sort of does it but not perfectly. Same in webkit browsers, though

Comment: haven't tested but isn't this solved by setting: -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); and equivalent for other browsers to force gpu kicking in even though opacity is at 100%? The issue otherwise is that at 100% opacity the gpu hands the rendering to the cpu instead causing the flickering. Some more info at: http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took so long I got distracted...:(
Anyway here your answer if you culdn't figure out yourself...
The magic is in text-align:center, BUT be sure to change your jquery code like this (NOTICE:"table"):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('table').css('visibility', 'visible').css('opacity', 0).animate({opacity: 1 }, 2000);
 });
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fYM6R/)

```
table
{
visibility:hidden;
background-color:#cccccc;
width:385px;
margin:0 auto;

}

td{text-align:center;}
th{text-align:center;}
```

Comment: Yup that is better way to do it... jsfiddle.net/MaXaS/12

Comment: We're getting there, that appears to work in the fiddle, but in my own code there is a problem with the headers not being correctly aligned... I will try to update the fiddle to show it.

Comment: OK! Update your fiddle so we can see the problem:)

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/MaXaS/13/ try uncommenting the display:block to see. Stuff gets clumped up, I guess since it's not a table-row anymore it ignores the rules of alignment

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8QJPv/1/ is a simpler example, as you increase the width of the first header, the <tr> does not match it

Comment: There you go, sorry it took so long:(

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the GPU acceleration. I tested my theory by adding the following:

```
tr {
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

With this in place, I think the font is rendered and faded, where in your jsfiddle, it is rerendered when the opacity hits 100%. This may or may not be an issue in IE9/10/Gecko browsers; you'll have to test there and see if you can trick the acceleration by antialiasing the text.